# URL rewriting - removing hash

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, hash, url-rewriting, swfaddress

How can I remove the hash sign (#) from the page's URL ?
I am using the SWFAddress plugin (jQuery) for deep linking purposes.

I need to replace this

> localhost/site/#blog

by

> localhost/site/blog

(Yes, #blog is just an anchor).

Somehow url rewriting in .htaccess doesn't work

> RewriteRule /blog #blog [L]

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The bit with the hash in the URL is not sent to the server when requesting a page, so you can't use redirect rules like that. It's client-side only.

Answer (score 12):

As the URL fragment is not transmitted to the server, you can only use a client side solution. Here’s one using JavaScript:

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
    location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/?#/, "/"));
}
```

This simply checks if there is a `#` in the URL and replaces the first occurrence with `/`. So `/site/#blog` would get `/site/blog`.

Comment: But that's completely different.. It's not just a different way of writing the url.