# A little bit help in url rewriting, please!

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a short question about url rewriting...

I have a website. Let's say `http://www.example.com/`

with some subsites:

```
http://www.example.com/a.php
http://www.example.com/b.php
```

etc...

and some "special" urls like

```
http://www.example.com/c.php?i=1#link1
http://www.example.com/c.php?i=1#link2
http://www.example.com/c.php?i=2#link1
```

Now I would like to write a .htaccess file to convert current urls into rewritten urls like

```
http://www.example.com/a/
http://www.example.com/c/1/#link1
```

I'm not an expert in url rewriting, so could somebody please help me?

Best reagards.

Comment: When asking a url-rewriting question, it is most helpful if you provide some input-output pairs. One specific example, and the general rule, in plain English, would be good.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^a$ a.php [L]

RewriteRule ^c/(.*)/(.*) c.php?i=$1$2
```

Comment: maybe little bit more general (without a.php and c.php)?

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^a.php a/
RewriteRule ^b.php b/
```

Should work as far as your static pages go, you can not rewrite the hash because the hash is not sent to the server (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991626/url-rewriting-removing-hash)). If you need to rewrite the hash I would suggest changing the hash to another GET variable (eg `u`), in that case just add this to your htaccess: `RewriteRule ^c.php?i=(.*)&u=(.*) c/$1/$2`. If you simply intend to leave the anchor though, you can omit it from your rewrite and everything should be fine (...becuase the server never sees the hash/pound symbol), and in that case you should add this to your code `RewriteRule ^c.php?i=(.*) c/$1/`.

Comment: RewriteRule ^b.php b/    whats this rule doing?

Comment: He said he had some static pages and cited `http://www.example.com/a.php` and `http://www.example.com/b.php` as examples. I'm just being thorough and telling him how he could rewrite if he had another page.