# Redirect to url with hashtag .htaccess Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I do something like this:

```
Redirect 301 /link-to-something https://otherwebsite.com/#something
```

In my .htaccess?
I've looked everywhere, this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^link-to-something/?$ https://otherwebsite.com/#something [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

But it doesn't for me, probably missed something, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Are you using `RewriteEngine On` at the top of your rules?

Comment: Indeed, I am. Then, should the RewriteRule I mentioned just work as is?

Comment: Yes it should.  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Sorry I can't add more then the "It doesn't work". It just doesn't redirect or do anything at all. I've tried incognito, but it makes no difference. As if there is no RewriteRule there.

Comment: This older topic suggests that hashtags are only processed on client side, not server-side and therefore can't be rewritten like that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484852/hash-character-in-urls-accessing-and-redirecting-in-apache

Comment: @HelloFishy It is possible to redirect to a URL containing `Hashtag` using htaccess . But you can't rewrite to the hashtag URI. Op is trying to redirect not rewrite the fragment.

Comment: Arnold : what url are you going to?