# apache 2.4 proxypass url with hash '#' character

Tags: apache, centos7, proxypass

I searched around but actually couldn't find how to pass the hashtag character on the proxypass, does somebody know any workaround on this?

```
<Location /UrlExsposed>
        ProxyPass  http://10.1.1.100:8080/#/internal/url
        ProxyPassReverse http://10.1.1.100:8080/#/internal/url
        ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
```

Actually I get this error,

```
Error response
Error code: 404

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND - Nothing matches the given URI.
```

I have already checked this, but as the post is pretty old I was wondering if there have been any evolutions on this?

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484852/hash-character-in-urls-accessing-and-redirecting-in-apache
```