# How redirect specific url using htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect this URL:

```
http://domain.com/index.html#!
```

To this One:

```
http://domain.com/
```

Using htaccess rewrite rules?

Comment: What have you tried? Everything after `#` will not be sent in a request to the server. `#!` suggests you are using some kind of ajax framework. Redirecting `index.php` to `/` should be trivial if you read the documentation and/or examples.

Comment: Read this: [URL rewriting - removing hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991626/url-rewriting-removing-hash)

Answer (score 0):

For `/index.html` to `/` you need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.html
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

That could incidentally fix the `#!` part of your URL as well, but that part of the URL is called a **fragment**, and is added there by something that's on the client side, it stays on the client side, and it is *never* transmitted to the server. So no htaccess or server side anything is going to know it's even there. If you want to remove it, you need to figure out what script is adding it there and remove the script. If you simply add javacsript to remove it, that other script may inadvertently add it back.

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
    location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/?#/, "/"));
}
```