# How to redirect a specific page to home page in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect a specific page to home page.

My source URL is `http://examlple.com/index.html?page=22`

My target URL is `http://examlple.com/`

I have tried `Redirect /index.html?page=22 http://example.com/`

also I have tried by using 301 and RewriteRule but no success yet, this is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How redirect specific url using htaccess rewrite rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466146/how-redirect-specific-url-using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against querystrings in **Redirect** directive.

Try mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=22$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://example.com/? [NC,L,R]
```

Empty question **?** mark at the end is important as it will discard the original query string from url.

Comment: if i use the your code its not working for me. can you suggest me anything?

Comment: My code is working fine on my apache server, it redirects http://example.com/index.html?page=22 to http://example.com .Do u have any other rules in htaccess that can conflict with this one?

Comment: no there is no rule. my url is http://examlple.com/?page_id=22  and this page redirect to http://examlple.com/ without any query string

Comment: Ok, if you want query strings to be appended to the target url, then remove the **?** from **http://example.com/?**

Comment: sorry to say its not working for me, have you any solution?

Comment: what happens when you type http://example.com/index.html?page=22 ? with **index.html**

Comment: same page loaded, don't redirected to home page

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled on your server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95646/discussion-between-psanjib-and-starkeen).

Comment: sorry , you are right mod_rewrite is not enable, let me check by enabling thanks for you help