# How to remove hash sign (#) from url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**I have a url look like this :**

> http://example.com/some_url_results#nights

When I opened this nothing will shown on page.

But When I removed # sign it perfectly working.

How I can remove # sign using .htaccess

Comment: You cannot do it from htaccess, it has to be done in Javascript.

Comment: In javascript I know how to remove. I can also remove it using php. But I want to remove this from .htaccess

Comment: @ZartashZulfiqar - I'm not quite sure if you read that properly. It cannot be done with `.htaccess`.

Comment: See: [URL rewriting - removing hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991626/url-rewriting-removing-hash)